# How do I load hierarchical data from a database into a tree view

Tags: treeview, lazarus

I have a database table with data and need to load the fields into a `TTreeView` object.

The line:

```
ItemTree.Items.AddChild(nil, CurrentField_Text);
```

simply adds a node to the top level.

How can I specify a point to insert it in?

Please note that while looping through the data from the table, I may (for example) insert 3 top level items and then the 4th element is actually the child of node 2.

How can I specify this?

Comment: Delphi or Lazarus? Please pick one. Or can we choose whichever suits us?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm surprised with your question as a new freepascal user. I thoughtthat they were similar (but not identical). So I didn't think it would have made a difference. Anyway, I'm using Lazarus.

Comment: They are similar but not identical. So, let's tag it Lazarus since that's is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some code lifted directly from a program of mine which inserts values taken from a query into a treeview.

```
 tv.items.clear;
 with qCustTree do  // this is the query which 'feeds' the treeview
  try
   close;
   params[0].asinteger:= qCustWithCallsID.asinteger;
   open;
   tv.items.BeginUpdate;
  while not eof do
   begin
    father:= fieldbyname ('father').asinteger;
    if father = 0
     then node:= nil
     else node:= FindANode (father);
    lastnode:= tv.Items.AddChildObject (node, fieldbyname ('curdate').asstring,
                                        pointer (fieldbyname ('id').asinteger));
    next
   end;
  finally
   tv.items.endupdate;
   tv.fullexpand;
   tv.Selected:= tv.Items[0];
   tvchange (nil, tv.Selected);
  end;
```

If the 'father' field of the returned tuple is 0, then a new parent node is opened on the tree, otherwise a new child node is opened.

Comment: @noam-newman This looks promising... What is POINTER? Is it visible on the tree?

Comment: @itsols: every node has a 'data' field in which can be stored a pointer to data. In the code, I am saving in this field the value of the 'id' field in the tuple, so that when a user clicks on the node, it 'knows' to which record it is pointing. This data is not visible; only the date appears. Of course, your code may need to display something different.

Comment: @noam-newman I get this error: `Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 3: Got "AnsiString", expected "Pointer"` when trying to `AddChildObject`. The ID in my case is a string. Isn't this possible?

Comment: @itsols: it's impossible to debug without seeing your code. AddChildObject takes three parameters: a node, a string and a pointer (or longint). It looks like you're trying to store a string in the pointer field - you can't do this! If the ID is a string, then you will have to find some other method of storing the ID within the tree. See this article: http://delphi.about.com/od/ttreeview/a/store-more-custom-data-into-tree-node-tree-view-delphi.htm

Comment: @noam-newman +1 for that and many thanks for your assistance. I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Use the parent node instead of `nil` in the call to `AddChild`, so that the child is added to the parent node:

```
ParentNode := ItemTree.Items.AddChild(nil, 'Parent');
ItemTree.Items.AddChild(ParentNode, 'Child node');
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip... Each category has a category code. Is there a way to store this code on the tree? This code is String.