# Loading Tree from Database

Tags: sql, oracle, tree

I have some Categories, but some of them have sub-categories. So I have a Tree.

I created a table which called **Categories**. The **id** field is the primary key the other field is **PARENTID**  which is foreign key referenced by the **id** ( To make it hierarchical).  you can have a view of data here

[image]

I am going to specify a certain **id**  and the query gives me the **id**'s of that category **and all sub-categories**. I have red [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8355/Trees-in-SQL-databases) 
 and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225429/how-do-i-load-hierarchical-data-from-a-database-into-a-tree-view) ,but none of them are not useful.

*one more point: I am not asking you to write the query for me. I am just looking for some hints*

Comment: Look into Recursive CTEs. Actually come to think of it you didn't mention which flavour of SQL you are using...

Comment: Which DB you are using? If you are using SQL Server recursive CTE will do.

Comment: @MillerKoijam: That's not a SQL Server "speciality". Postgres, Firebird, Oracle, Teradata, DB2 and Cubrid also support recursive queries.

Comment: But i hope mysql does not support recursive CTE, thats why i ask which DB? Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name for pointing out.

Comment: @MillerKoijam i am using Oracle

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest two options.

1) specify your select to include sub cursors,

```
select column1, cursor(select * form table2) as cursorOfTable2 from table1
```

and then in your middle tier code, you can reference the sub cursor, the implementation varies depending on what your middle tier is (j2ee, .net, ...)

2) specify the parent child relationship within your select

```
select a.id as parentId, b.id as child_id, from table1 a, table2 b
where a.id = b.parentId
```

And then again in your middle tier code you can create the parent child data structure with this data.

hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a related link which contains more explanations?

Comment: what would you like explanations for?